# Remove 2 Entries from Navigation Journal

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my `windows phone 8` app i have to check if user is already login or not before navigating to different pages. If user is not logged in i navigate the user to `Login.xaml` from where user chooses either login from Facebook or twitter or cancel.

Now when user successfully logs in i navigate the user to appropriate page. My question is how to remove those potential 2 pages (login.xaml and facebook/twitter login)?

```
NavigationService.BackStack is IEnumerable :(
```

does anyone has a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the same as using the WPF `NavigationService` then you can use [RemoveBackEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after you have navigated to the new page.

---

Update:

If you are using code such as

```
if (!user.IsLoggedIn)
{
  NavigationService.Navigate(new Login());
}
```

Then you can remove the back entries before anyone has a chance to see them

```
if (!user.IsLoggedIn)
{
  NavigationService.Navigate(new Login());
  //Hide back entry
  NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

However if you are unable to do this, for example when you end up with a Facebook/twitter url in the back entry, then instead subscribe to the [Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and then remove them

```
public Login()
{
   NavigationService.Navigated += HideEntriesOnNavigated;
}

void HideEntriesOnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  if (IsFacebookLogin(e.Url)
    || IsTwitterLogin(e.Url)
    || IsAppLoginPage(e.Url))
  {
     NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
  }
}
```

Comment: it is a very very very straight forward answer, i said about multiple scenarios in which in backstack login pages may exist or not. so i have to check whether backstack contains the pages then remove them. cn you help me on that?

Comment: You can only ever remove one, so the trick is to remove them as soon as they get added. See the update. Also, please post some code as I'm having to guess what you are doing now

Comment: thanks for the solution, i just removed the unwanted entries whenever they are navigated.