# how to clear Navigation history in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a WPF app using its Page and NavigationWindow, but I don't need its navigation history at all (maybe chose the wrong app type?), which is causing memory leak.

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948509/remove-2-entries-from-navigation-journal), i am using `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();` following every navigation, like follows

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new MyPage());
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

But it is not working because the app still eats up more and more memory as it runs, and it still allows backwards navigation when the navigation bar is shown. Anyway to clear the navigation history? Any recommendation for a structure more suitable than NavigationWindow+Page?

Comment: Have you looked at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1925192/3178690

Answer (score 2):

As Conroy said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38318202/3113406), NavigationWindow should not be used.

Maybe a TabControl on a Window would better suit the program. 

Anyway, here is a solution for clearing all the "previous" back entries in the NavigationService:

C#:

```
while (NavigationService.CanGoBack) {
    try {
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        break;
    }
}
```

VB.NET:

```
While NavigationService.CanGoBack
    Try
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit While
    End Try
End While
```

Code Explanation:

- While loop keeps running while there are back entries.
- During each loop a back entry is removed.
- While loop exits when there are no more back entries

Answer (score -2):

Why do you use `NavigationService` if you don't need it?
You can use `Content` property of `Window`.

`this.Content = new MyPage();`